# How to preview html file in a browser using Vim? any keyboard shortcut?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am new to Vim world. I want to use Vim for web development. Anyone know how to display your html file in a browser, any short-cuts? Thank you

Comment: How about this plugin? https://github.com/MikeCoder/open-in-browser.vim

Answer (score 4):

On a Mac, I would use

```
:w | !open %
```

On other systems, instead of `open` you can use (courtesy of http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/open-files-urls.html)

- `xdg-open`:  many Linux distributions
- `cygstart`:  Windows with Cygwin
- `cmd /c start`:  Windows

If you want a shortcut, then add something like

```
:nmap <F5> :w <Bar> !open %<CR>
```

to your vimrc file.  If you want something that works across platforms, then you can borrow this function (but drop `drupal#` from the name) from https://drupal.org/project/vimrc:

```
" @function drupal#OpenCommand() {{{
" Return a string that can be used to open URL's (and other things).
" Usage:
" let open = drupal#OpenCommand()
" if strlen(open) | execute '!' . open 'http://example.com' | endif
" @see http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/open-files-urls.html
function! drupal#OpenCommand() " {{{
if has('win32unix') && executable('cygstart')
  return 'cygstart'
elseif has('unix') && executable('xdg-open')
  return 'xdg-open'
elseif (has('win32') || has('win64')) && executable('cmd')
  return 'cmd /c start'
elseif (has('macunix') || has('unix') && system('uname') =~ 'Darwin')
      \ && executable('open')
  return 'open'
else
  return ''
endif
endfun " }}} }}}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention : I am using linux. When I am editing my html file in vim, to preview the file in a browser I put xdg-open in a command mode? I also added :nmap <F5> :w <Bar> !open % to my vimrc , but when i press f5 it doesnt react

Comment: thanks for the vimrc command. Minor thing, if you don't want to hit enter each time add `<CR>` at the end like this: `nmap <F1> :w <Bar> !open %<CR>`

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, a simple command is

```
:! start %
```

That executes the Windows `start` command, which figures out that the current HTML file (`%`) should be opened in the (default) web browser (based on the file extension).

On other platforms, try commands like `xdg-open`, `open`, or `firefox` directly.

That simplistic command doesn't deal with all situations; for a more robust solution, look at plugins like [open-browser.vim - Open URI with your favorite browser](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3133).

Answer (score 0):

A simplified version of Ingo Karkat's answer is attempting to open the HTML file. On Windows usually the default program for this is a browser:

```
:!%
```